# A nice functional equation

Tags: functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ a function such that
$$f(x, y)f(y, z)=f(x, z).$$
Show that $\displaystyle f(x, y)=\frac{h(x)}{h(y)}$.

Comment: $f(x,y)=0$ is also a solution

Comment: ...except trivial solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Surely just divide by $f(y,z)$ thus $f(x,y) = f(x,z)/f(y,z)$, then rewrite $f(\cdot,z) = h(\cdot)$ giving the answer.

Alternatively just check what $f(x,y) = h(x)/h(y)$ gives: $$\frac{h(x)}{h(y)}\frac{h(y)}{h(z)} = \frac{h(x)}{h(z)}$$ the $h(y)$'s on the left cancel confirming it is  a solution.

Comment: @Downvoter, please say what is wrong with this an as answer?

Comment: You have to show that $f(x,y)=h(x)/h(y)$ is the unique solution, not just a solution.

Comment: That wasn't specified in your question.